# How to - simple process module in CRAM

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am learning about CRAM designators and process modules. At this moment I am trying to create a stupid process module to check if I understand how the system works.

I am following [this tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/cram_process_modules) but I have not succeeded.

When I execute the following code:

```
CPL> (def-process-module navigation (input-designator)
          (let ((goal-pose (reference input-designator)))
            (or (execute-navigation-action goal-pose)
                (fail 'navigation-failed))))
```

An error is raised in SLIME:

```
The variable NAVIGATION is unbound.
    [Condition of type UNBOUND-VARIABLE]
```

I don't understand why this is happening. "Navigation" is the name of the process module I am trying to define, am I right? Therefore, I can understand an error raised because "execute-navigation-action" is not defined but not in "navigation". What I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49064/how-to---simple-process-module-in-cram/) by [dgerod](https://answers.ros.org/users/1843/dgerod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2012-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are in the wrong package. First load the package `cram_process_modules`:

```
(ros-load:load-system "cram_process_modules" :process-modules)
```

Then switch to the right package:

```
(in-package :cpm)
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dgerod](https://answers.ros.org/users/1843/dgerod/) on 2012-11-25**:
Perfect!!! Thanks a lot.